# CouchDB on Ubuntu VM in Azure does not start

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb

I am evaluating CouchDB for a new project where it would be a perfect fit instead of the DB I usually use (Mongo). However, the installation seems to have problems.
I have installed all dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install erlang-base-hipe
sudo apt-get install erlang-dev
sudo apt-get install erlang-manpages
sudo apt-get install erlang-eunit
sudo apt-get install erlang-nox
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
sudo apt-get install libmozjs-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

And went for a rep installation. However, even if start the service it seems to start, but when entering the db with couchdb I get an error message

```
Apache CouchDB 1.5.0 (LogLevel=info) is starting.
Failure to start Mochiweb: eaddrinuse
[error] [<0.107.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                     {<0.107.0>,crash_report,
                      [[{initial_call,
                         {mochiweb_socket_server,init,['Argument__1']}},
                        {pid,<0.107.0>},
                        {registered_name,[]},
                        {error_info,
                         {exit,eaddrinuse,
                          [{gen_server,init_it,6,
                            [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,320}]},
                           {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                            [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},
                        {ancestors,
                         [couch_secondary_services,couch_server_sup,<0.32.0>]},
                        {messages,[]},
                        {links,[<0.94.0>]},
                        {dictionary,[]},
                        {trap_exit,true},
                        {status,running},
                        {heap_size,987},
                        {stack_size,27},
                        {reductions,597}],
                       []]}}
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_secondary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,httpd,eaddrinuse}}}}}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,98}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,269}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Thanks for any suggestion and please remember I am a first time user of couchdb.

Comment: But it seems to be working somewhat since if I do curl localhost:5984 I get the proper answer 
{"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"d884f33533f493499a338dcaa20cb82b","version":"1.5.0","vendor":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"14.04"}}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my problem is the fact that I did not open a port on my azure VM. I am posting this in case anybody gets the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The couchdb version that's in the base repositories is old: 1.5.0.   You definitely want to use 1.6.1.  I'm running a CouchDB 1.6.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS node in Azure and I'm not seeing the problem you describe.

Here are the commands to upgrade to 1.6.1 (backup your databases first):

```
sudo apt-get remove couchdb couchdb-bin couchdb-common -f
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:couchdb/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install couchdb couchdb-bin couchdb-common -f
```

Taken from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640288/how-to-install-latest-couchdb-on-ubuntu?newreg=6187cf3871f24d89bf563547099aa8f2#640314)

Answer (score 0):

As per the provided error message, CouchDB is already up & running on your VM, Or some service is running on port 5984 (couchdb default port) in your VM.

```
**{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,httpd,eaddrinuse}}}}}}**
```

That's the reason for the couchdb failed to start Because the couchdb configured port occupied by a service on your VM (it may be couchdb service or other service running on the same port)

kill the service running on couchDB default port using the following command:

```
/bin/ps aux | grep couchdb | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Start CouchDB again:

```
service couchdb start
```